# Apache Connection Time Out

Tags: php, apache, laravel, ubuntu-14.04

I have a report that generates an array of data from MySQL server by using looping through PHP code (Laravel framework). However, the maximum that the server can handle is an array with 400 row, and each row contains 61 child value in it.

```
[
 [1, ...,61], // row 1
 .
 .
 .
 [1,....,61] // row 400
]
```

Each value is calculated from running a loop that retrieves data from MySQL server.

There is a no load balancer.

I tried to increase ***max_execution_time = 600 (10 minutes)***, but it still show the connection time out problem. Any thoughts? Thanks,

```
Connection Timed Out

Description: Connection Timed Out
```

**Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) - PHP 5.6**

Comment: Thanks for that info.  Might be caught up by this one: [mod_proxy_fcgi ignores timeout (fixed at 30s)](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1222328).  FYI... the [IUS](https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/6/x86_64/repoview/) repositories offer 2.4.25

Comment: Thanks @ficuscr. I think that bug is fixed on version 2.4.8, they doesn't mention the version 2.4.7 at all. I will give it a read though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My PHP version was 5.6. After upgrading to PHP7, my application speed was increased significantly. Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Would need more info for a definitive answer...

2. What is the Apache/httpd version (there have been some bugs that relate to this)?
3. Is there a firewall or load balancer in the mix?

If you are sure it is still a timeout error and not say memory, then it is probably httpd's [`TimeOut` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#timeout).  It defaults to 300 seconds.

If still stuck paste the exact error you are seeing.